# Python - a Class to get employee age from Date of birth?

Tags: python, oop, python-class

```
import datetime
class Employee:
    def __init__ (self,first,last,pay,dob):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + "." + last + "@company.com"
        self.dob = dob
    
    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first,self.last)
    
    def age(dob):
        today = date.today()
        return today.year - dob.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (dob.month, dob.day))
         
    
emp1 = Employee("aa","ss",122,date(1991,2,3))
emp2 = Employee("ww","ii",637,date(1997,8,24))
emp3 = Employee("ee","oo",986,date(1986,10,19))

#driver code
print(Employee.age(emp2))
```

I am getting the below error:

> AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'year'

What is incorrect in this?

Comment: The first argument to a method is `self`, not `dob`. What you're calling `dob` in `def age(dob)` is actually the `Employee` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Employee.age()` method signature has only one argument - `dob`. When you call it first argument that is passed is the instance. By convention we use argument `self` for it. But you use `dob`. Stick to convention as you do in the other method. then work with `self.dob.year`

```
from datetime import date
class Employee:
    def __init__ (self,first,last,pay,dob):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + "." + last + "@company.com"
        self.dob = dob
    
    @property
    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last) # in 3.6 return f'{self.first} {self.last}'
    
    def age(self):
        today = date.today()
        return today.year - self.dob.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (self.dob.month, self.dob.day))
         
    
emp1 = Employee("aa","ss",122,date(1991,2,3))
emp2 = Employee("ww","ii",637,date(1997,8,24))
emp3 = Employee("ee","oo",986,date(1986,10,19))

#driver code
print(emp1.age())
```

Note, I also added @property decorator, so that fullname is "read-only" property
and also fixed the import

in 3.6+ you can use f-strings. `age` and `e-mail property`, like `fullname` may be read-only property (i.e. you should not specify age that contradict to `dob`), e.g.

```
@property
def age(self):
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - self.dob.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (self.dob.month, self.dob.day))
```

Then you can use it like this

```
print(emp1.age) # note the difference when it is method in the original class, and now when its property
```

Comment: You definetely mean `print(emp2.age())`.

Comment: @Adirio, absolutely. there were so many issues to fix in the class, that I overlooked the last line. fixed it.

Comment: It it was my class, I would also turn the `age` method into a property, this is, add `@property` before the `age` method and use it as `print(emp1.age)` instead of `print(emp1.age())`. You could recommend him to also do that change explaining these two changes so that he sees the diference of a method and a property.

Comment: @Adirio yeah, I just mentioned it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `employee` class does not have a year attribute

but

`employee.dob` has that

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
class Employee:
    def __init__ (self,first,last,pay,dob):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + "." + last + "@company.com"
        self.dob = dob
    
    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first,self.last)
    
    def age(dob):
        today = date.today()
        dob = dob.dob # get dob from the object(of employee class) <<<<< Single change
        return today.year - dob.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (dob.month, dob.day))
         
    
emp1 = Employee("aa","ss",122,date(1991,2,3))
emp2 = Employee("ww","ii",637,date(1997,8,24))
emp3 = Employee("ee","oo",986,date(1986,10,19))

#driver code
print(Employee.age(emp2))
```

Comment: Using `dob` that stands for 'date of birth' as parameter name for the instance instead of the conventional `self` is not a good idea...

Comment: I just wanted to purpose minimal change option and explain the reason! But I agree with your point, thanks for commenting

Comment: Correcting common errors will also help him improve his skills, and that includes using `print(emp2.age())` instead of `print(Employee.age(emp2))`